# Global parameter that is changed subtly within each parameterize specification in py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

For my scenario I want to be able to verify that my validate functions are working properly. So that means I need to be able to feed all combinations of possible inputs of the json object that I'm validating. The json I'm expecting is of the following format and requires the following types and keys:

```
{ 
  "id": str, 
  "name": str, 
  "item_list": list, 
  "language_list": list, 
  "number", int 
}
```

So an example would be:

```
myDict= dict({
    "id": 'test_id',
    'name': 'test_name',
    'item_list': ['foo', 'bar'],
    'language_list': ['spanish', 'english'],
    'number': 2
})
```

I currently have something like the following to test that incorrect input is being handled properly.

```
({ @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", [
    ({
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test_name",
        "item_list": ["foo", "bar"],
        "language_list": ["spanish", "english"],
        "number": 2
    }),
    ({
        "id": ["some", "list"],
        "name": "test_name",
        "item_list": ["foo", "bar"],
        "language_list": ["spanish", "english"],
        "number": 2
    }),
    ({
        "id": {"another_key": "another_value"},
        "name": "test_name",
        "item_list": ["foo", "bar"],
        "language_list": ["spanish", "english"],
        "number": 2
    }),
    .
    .
    .

])
def test_validate_json_error(test_input):
    # dont worry about the below. Im just handling the input
    with pytest.raises(CustomFlaskError):
        validate_json(test_input)

})
```

I want to be able to do that for all keys of my dictionary. So is there a way to do this in a more succinct way? So maybe define the correct example of myDict as a global then in each parametrize change it a bit. So like the following:

```
({ @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", [
    (myDict["id"] = 1),
    (myDict["id"] = ["some", "list"]),
    (myDict["id"] = {"another_key": "another_value"}),
    .
    .
    .

])
def test_validate_json_error(test_input):
    # dont worry about the below. Im just handling the input
    with pytest.raises(CustomFlaskError):
        validate_json(test_input)

})
```

This looks a lot better especially which json objects with large amount of keys.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just needed to have a function that performs a shallow copy of the variable which also takes the key that I want to be changed in the json with the value I want to replace it with. It returns the changed shallow copy which is then used in the parametrized.

So the following works

```
def modify(k, v):
    copyDict = myDict.copy
    copyDict[k] = v
    return copyDict

({ @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input", [
    (modify("id", 1),
    (modify("id", ["some", "list"]),
    (modify("id",  {"another_key": "another_value"}),
    .
    .
    .

])
def test_validate_json_error(test_input):
    # dont worry about the below. Im just handling the input
    with pytest.raises(CustomFlaskError):
        validate_json(test_input)

})
```